# Simplifying $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{n(n!)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial, factoring

How can I prove this equality:
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{n(n!)}= \frac{-1}{n(n+1)(n+1)!}
$$

Comment: Just bring everything to the same common denominator (which should be $n(n+1)(n+1)!$ here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{n(n!)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(n+1)n!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)n!} - \frac{1}{n(n!)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)} - \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(-\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}+ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)}\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{-1}{n(n+1)(n+1)!}$$

Comment: I was stuck on the second, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{n(n!)}=\color{red}1\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \color{red}{\frac{n+1}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=$$

$$=\left( \color{red}{ 1+ \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{n+1}{n} }\right)\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$